# Moved Bitcoin Core wallet.dat to a new PC and after the block chain was updated it's shown as almost empty

Tags: wallet

I moved Bitcoin Core wallet.dat to a new PC and after the block chain was updated it's shown as almost empty. On the old PC that is also synced it shows what I think it the correct amount.

The wallet shows the same transactions with the same dates as the old PC. The new PC did have some of the block chain already downloaded before I moved the wallet DAT file.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The same wallet.dat on the new PC shows almost no (0.0133...) Bitcoins. On the old PC it had more. The old PC is synced and up to date. Why is the new one wrong.

Comment: Is the new one synced?

Comment: Yes, they both are synced and show the same transaction history but the available amount differ on each.

Comment: Did someone figure out how to steal from offline wallets? I used Blockonomics to look up my transitions and every single deposit I made is there in the exact amount but all the sent amounts are off a little at first and then don't match at all at the end and is missing a few of the last ones I sent. ??? :(